# Mapping dropdown selects to URL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, user-interface, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular and I can't get my dropdown selectes to map to the browser URL (dynamic based on dropdown selections).

For example, the browser URL is "/home?color=Red&&size=Large". When I paste this URL in a new tab, I want the color and size dropdowns to already be selected as Red and Large. How do I do this?

My AngularJS controller code:

```
$scope.getResults = function() {

    server.getResults($scope.myColor, $scope.mySize)
    .success(function(data) {
        results = data;

        $scope.myColor = $location.search('color', $scope.myColor);
        $scope.mySize = $location.search('size', $scope.mySize);
    });
};
```

AngularJS service for the above function:

```
app.factory('server', ['$http', function($http){
    return { 
        getResults : function(color, size) {
            var req = {};
            req.color = color;
            req.size = size;

            return $http({
                method: 'GET', 
                url: 'results',
                params : req
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

ui-router in Angular:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this Solution**

ui-router in Angular:

```
 $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/home/:color/:size',
        templateUrl: '/home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams)
   {  
        $scope.color=$stateParams.color;
         $scope.size=$stateParams.size;
   });
```

View

```
var params= { size:'24', color:red };
$state.go('home', params);
```

Comment: thanks could you possibly put this in a JSfiddle or plunker?

Comment: Also are you saying to make a new controller?

Comment: @jebmarcus you can use the controller which you assigned for the state